# undefined ng-repeat variable when passed from directive template to a controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive with a template that uses ng-repeat on an anchor tag creating a gallery of anchors. Each anchor also has an ng-click which when clicked calls a parent controller function. To this function is passed the ng-repeat item.

Problem : This item when accessed inside the parent controller method is undefined

Here is a test scenario to simulate the similar situation

```
<testdirective func="show(x)" items="buttons"></testdirective>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/43aNqFS71Jn9vOdh6AG2?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two changes you need to make.

in your **index.html** make a refrence to your function:

```
    <testdirective func="show" items="buttons"></testdirective>
```

and in your **testdirective** change your template like so:

```
  template: '<button ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="func()(item)" id="submit" />{{item}}</button>',
```

Notice the change in the ng-click - first brackets is to get a refrence to the function itself and the second is to invoke the function with the paramater.

I also made a fork of your plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nECPbL8YoToi0jP9HJHQ?p=preview

Please tell me if that's what you wanted to achieve

Comment: Superb ! Where did you get this trick from :). I searched all over and did not find any reference to this kind of parameter passing. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your directive should bind to a controller, change it as follows,

```
app.directive("testdirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: 'testController',
    template: '<button ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="show(item)" id="submit" />{{item}}</button>',
    scope: {
      items: "=",
      func: '&'
    }

  };
});
```

**DEMO**

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('testController', function($scope) {

  $scope.buttons = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5'];

  $scope.show = function(x) {
    alert(x);
  }
})


app.directive("testdirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: 'testController',
    template: '<button ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="show(item)" id="submit" />{{item}}</button>',
    scope: {
      items: "=",
      func: '&'
    }

  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='test'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-rc.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1> {{ testValue }}
    
    <testdirective func="show(x)" items="buttons"></testdirective>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes i understand, but then this is not a reusable directive because its bound to a controller isnt it.

Comment: what do you mean by not reusable?  no you can reuse it

Comment: you have explicitly bound it to `controller: 'testController'` so its tightly coupled.